# What what is "project " referring to? (Intellij Plugin)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

It says cannot resolve symbol.

```
Document currentDoc = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedTextEditor().getDocument();
```

Example 2:

```
StatusBar statusBar = WindowManager.getInstance().getStatusBar(project);
if (statusBar != null) statusBar.addWidget(widget, [Anchor], [disposable]);
```

Comment: `project` is of type `com.intellij.openapi.project.Project`. You can obtain the current project depending on the context. It depends *where* this code snippet is

Comment: Refer to these: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206795775-Get-current-Project-current-file-in-editor, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206135019-How-to-get-current-Project-the-project-with-user-focus-, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206763335-Getting-active-project-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method i use and recommend:

```
AnActionEvent.getData(LangDataKeys.PROJECT);
```

You can include it like that:

```
AnActionEvent.getProject()
```

The answer is in the comments:

Refer to these:

[Jetbrains Community post 1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206795775-Get-current-Project-current-file-in-editor)

[Jetbrains Community post 2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206135019-How-to-get-current-Project-the-project-with-user-focus-)

[Jetbrains Community post 3](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206763335-Getting-active-project-)